Check in a Github Action Post-step if any previous step in the same job has failed
I'm writing a custom GitHub Action. What the action is actually supposed to do is secondary. It has a post step, to do some cleanup after all other actions in the job have finished. This post step even runs when the job is failing, which is exactly what I want. To do its job properly, however, it needs to know if any of the previous steps has failed. That sounds very simple, but turns out to be surprisingly hard to do.
What I have tried so far:

The yaml for the action allows for post-if to make the post step only run under specific conditions, for example if the job is failing. This doesn't work for me because I always need to do cleanup, not just when it was successful or failing. I need to know, however, if something failed to do the cleanup correctly.
I tried using the GitHub API to check the current state of the job and search for any failed steps. However, this produces two separate followup problems: (1) how to find the correct job via the API, and (2) how to get up-to-date information from the API. Concerning (1), The API provides a RUN_ID, which makes it easy to identify the correct workflow run. The job inside the workflow seems to have a unique ID in the API, but the ID is not available via env var or context inside the action. We can compare the name of the job in the API result with the value in the env var GITHUB_JOB. Unfortunately, the names don't seem to be the same. The name in the env var is the name exactly how it is defined in the yaml, the name that is provided via the API has a prefix (just like in the webui) with the outer workflow in case its a re-usable workflow, and has a postfix with the input parameters in case its a matrix execution. That makes it super hard to actually compare the name reliably. Concerning (2), the API seems to be lagging behind real time. I observed that the current state of the job run is up to a minute late, i.e., steps in the job that have long completed still show as in_progress and do not have a defined conclusion (success vs failure). That makes the check on whether all previous steps were successful impossible, because the latest steps (if some has failed it will be the latest ones) are still missing. I have also tried to add a 'Cache-Control: no-cache' header to the API calls, just in case the lag just because of an HTTP proxy / server-side cache, but without any improvement.
The job context seems to define a conclusion property which is failure or success, however, that context is only accessible in the workflow yaml, and not in the action yaml or via the @actions/* npm packages.

Any suggestions?

You can use an input field to get the job status.
The input field gets evaluated separately for main and post action, so you get the real status at the end for the post action.
See following action.yaml example
# ...

inputs:
  __job_status:
    description: 'DO NOT SET MANUALLY'
    default: '${{ job.status }}'

#...

In the action code you just read the input value of __job_status

this worked perfectly for me!
